# A graph, G, has a minimum vertex cover of size |V| - 1 if and only if G is complete. Is it true?

Tags: algorithm, vertex-cover

A mesh can be an example of a complete G. Where each node is connected to every other node. So shouldn't the minimum vertex cover size for such a graph is '1'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a graph theory question, not programming.

Comment: Suppose G is not complete. Then there's no edge between A and B for some two vertices A and B. Then the remaining vertices form a vertex cover, so the minimum vertex cover is of size at most |V|-2.Conversely, any set of N-1 vertices of K(N) is a vertex cover, and any set of N-2 vertices fails to cover one edge.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum vertex cover is the set of vertices such that every *edge* is touching a vertex in the set. Given a mesh (complete graph) of `A` `B` and `C`, if you only have one node (say `A`) as your attempted MVC, you're missing an edge (in this case the edge `B-C`).

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But how can we prove it mathematically? I don't know where to start.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? I think you should reword your question if you're looking for help with a proof.